# Is there any way to return soap fault messages on IIS?

Tags: wcf, iis, soap

I have a WCF service and it uses `Basic Authentication` on the level of `IIS`. I have some LDAP users which are added to `Authorization Rules`.

[image: Authorization Rules]

[image: Authentication Settings]

However, if a wrong user tries to consume service, it returns HTTP error page. It is normal to return an error but I want to return SOAP fault message.

**Is there any way to return soap fault messages for specific error codes on IIS?**

[image: Http error]